# The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: github

I installed Git and ran the set up my username and email.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email username@gmail.com
Add your public key
```

Next, I created a project directory called 'projectname' and committed this to a remote Git server.

```
mkdir projectname
cd projectname
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:projectname/projectname.git
git push origin master
```

My public key has been added to the github website.

When I try to commit I get this error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any suggestions? - I am working with Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you copy past the SSH key exactly like it's in the xxxx.pub file do not add lines or spaces to it.

Try again or delete both public and private keys and generate them again. It should work. Also remember to update the pub key again on Github website.

Also test your existing key with this command

ssh -T git@github.com

Comment: I have tried it but for some reason its not working at my end :|